# Under what conditions can epoxide undergo oxidation by HIO4

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

**Question**
[image]

**Doubt**

Can epoxide react with HIO4. I have  seen that in same cases they do. But in this given question they don't.  If they do react , then how  and what will be the products?Please help

Comment: You might be mistaken. The sugar you have depicted has no epoxide, it's an acetal.

Comment: This may assist you http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/vlu/vsc/en/ch/2/vlu/oxidation_reduktion/ox_spal_diol.vlu/Page/vsc/en/ch/2/oc/reaktionen/formale_systematik/oxidation_reduktion/oxidation/entfernen_wasserstoff/ox_spaltung_12_diole/anwendung.vscml.html